# How to stop the Date Picker Dialogue-box Date to set the previous Dates. It should allow only above System current date date

Tags: android

Hi every one thanks in advance..
   I have requirement in my App that I have a Date Picker to set the date. Now I want to restrict the Date Picker to set the date above System current dates but not below to the  System current date. How....? 
Can any one help me out from this.... And How to validate the System current date with the Date Picker Date.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can extend `DatePickerDialog` and make your own implementation of `OnDateChanged`, which is called everytime that the date changes and you get as parameters the DatePicker, and the new year, month and day values, so **you can check if that date is past and in that case throw the error (with a Toast or whatever) and call DatePicker.updateDate() to set a correct value (so that DatePicker is allways in a consistent state).**

Also, you can call to `DatePicker.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, onDateChangedListener);` then you can pass a

```
onDateChangedListener implementation without having to extend DatePickerDialog.
```

**EDIT:** (I never try this but I think it can done your work..)

[DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)'s

```
setMinDate(long minDate)
```

Sets the minimal date supported by this NumberPicker in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in getDefault() time zone.

Example:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday);         
dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date());
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me.... it resulted StackOverFlow exception and i handled it.....

Answer (score 2):

Use [setMinDate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29) function of [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) class. Here you can set your date in milli seconds. To prevent future dates use [setMaxDate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29)

Use [getDatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#getDatePicker%28%29) to get the datepicker and set calendarView as told above.

Comment: I want to restrict the Date Picker to not allow the user to set the date  below System current date...How? In Code???

Answer (score 2):

```
    private int myear; //Declare these three variables in MainActivity and call showDialog(1)
    private int mmonth;
    private int mday;

    final Calendar myCalendar= Calendar.getInstance();

    private void setCurrentDateOnView() {  //Call this method before showDialog

        myear  = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mmonth = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mday   = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {

                case 1:
                    DatePickerDialog startDate =   new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, myear,mmonth,
                            mday){
                        @Override
                        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                        {

                        }
                    };

                    myCalendar.set(myear, mmonth, mday);
                    long startTime = myCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    startDate.getDatePicker().setMinDate(startTime - 1000);
                    return startDate;
            }
            return null;
        }
```